# How to use Option with Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataset like this:

```
+----+------+
|code|status|
+-----------+
|   1| "new"|
|   2|  null|
|   3|  null|
+----+------+
```

I would like to write a UDF that depends on both columns.

I got it working following the second approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32358390/1450420) which is to handle `null` outside the UDF, and write `myFn` to take a Boolean as the second parameter:

```
df.withColumn("new_column",
  when(pst_regs("status").isNull, 
    myFnUdf($"code", lit(false))
  )
  .otherwise(
    myFnUdf($"code", lit(true))
  )
)
```

To handle null in the UDF an approach I looked at is per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39392888/1450420) which talks about "wrapping arguments with `Options`".  I tried code like this:

```
df.withColumn("new_column", myFnUdf($"code", $"status"))

def myFn(code: Int, status: String) = (code, Option(status)) match {
  case (1, "new") => "1_with_new_status"
  case (2, Some(_)) => "2_with_any_status"
  case (3, None) => "3_no_status"
}
```

But a row with `null` gives `type mismatch; found :None.type required String`.  I also tried wrapping an argument with `Option` during udf creation without success.  The basic form of this (without Option) looks like this:

```
myFnUdf = udf[String, Int, String](myFn(_:Int, _:String))
```

I'm new to Scala so I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Part of my confusion may be the different syntaxes for creating udfs from functions (e.g. per https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-udfs.html), so I'm not sure I'm using the best way.  Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

Edited to add missing `(1, "new")` case per @user6910411 and @sgvd comments.

Comment: I think you could make the myFn example work by saying `case (1,Some("new")) => "1_with_new_status"` so that all cases match the same tuple type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, there may be some code you are using that we are missing here. When I try your example `myFn`, made into a UDF with `val myFnUdf = udf(myFn _)` and run it with `df.withColumn("new_column", myFnUdf($"code", $"status")).show`, I don't get a type mismatch, but instead a `MatchError`, as also noted by user6910411. This is becausethere is no pattern to match `(1, "new")`.

Aside from that, although it is usually better to use Scala's Options rather than raw `null` values, you don't have to in this case. The following example works with `null` directly:

```
val my_udf = udf((code: Int, status: String) => status match {
    case null => "no status"
    case _ => "with status"
})

df.withColumn("new_column", my_udf($"code", $"status")).show
```

Result:

```
+----+------+-----------+
|code|status| new_column|
+----+------+-----------+
|   1|   new|with status|
|   2|  null|  no status|
|   2|  null|  no status|
+----+------+-----------+
```

Wrapping with options does still work though:

```
val my_udf = udf((code: Int, status: String) => Option(status) match {
    case None => "no status"
    case Some(_) => "with status"
})
```

This gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks @sgvd.  I got it working with both methods (and updated the question to include the missing case).  Appreciate your help.